# Placing tkinter widgets in foreground

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I cannot achieve to create a Textbox (using `tkinter`'s Text widget) which is in the background and having a Canvas item (e.g. an oval) over it (foregroud) :

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
c = Tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg='white')
o = c.create_oval(10, 10, 390, 390, fill='red')
c.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
t = Tk.Text(c)
t.place(x=10,y=10)
c.tag_lower(t)
c.tag_raise(o)
root.mainloop()
```

Even if I use `c.tag_lower(t)`, `c.tag_raise(o)`, it doesn't work. Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented behavior. You cannot draw over other widgets that are embedded in a canvas. There is no workaround. To be able to draw on top of text, your only option is to draw the text using `create_text`.

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to create a sub-canvas over the main canvas that would contain the `oval` in my example ? Then the oval would be over the text widget ?

Comment: No. The subcanvas would hide the text widget.